# Timed Indexed Color sets in CPN Tools that results in Unhandled Exception Error

Tags: sml, ml, petri-net

I am using CPN Tools to model a distributed system. CPN Tools uses CPN ML an extension of SML. The project homepage is: cpntools.org

I started with a simple model and when I try to make a particular indexed color set timed, I get an "Internal error". There is another indexed colorset within my Petri-net model that is timed and works correctly. I am not sure how I can troubleshoot since I don't understand the error message. Could you help me interpret the error message or give me some hints on what I could be doing wrong?

The model is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDAXU.jpg

The declarations of the model are:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RORCD.jpg

The error message is:

```
Internal error: Compile error when generating code. Caught error.../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27

structure CPN`TransitionID1413873858 = struct ... end (* see simulator debug info for full code *)

simglue.sml:884.12-884.43
```

"

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I run in the same problem and wasted too much time on this, so maybe it will help someone else in the future.

I didn't understand exactly the reason for this, but it seems the problem appears when you play with time values on an arch that ends to a transition (I was updating an integer value to the current time, using *IntInf.toInt(time())*). Now, if I move the code on the outgoing arch of that transition (that is: the one that ends in a place) there is no error.